# Comparing to date range with given date 

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table `tblleaveApplication` with columns `empid, leaveStarddate, leaveEndDate, leavetype, remarks` and so on.

I want to find the employee who is on leave by `leaveStarddate` and `leaveEndDate` given today's date.

Please help in this regard.

Comment: You should have a look at the [select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) statement. You can use that to do do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM tblLeaveApplication
WHERE LeaveStartDate >= getdate() and LeaveEndDate <= getdate()
```

?

Comment: When posting code, please highlight it and press the `{}` button, and check the preview to make it fit nicely on the page.

Comment: If their leave started today, this query isn't likely to pick them up (unless you happen to run it at midnight).